# How to display retrieved image from mysql in jsp. I am using struts2 and tiles

Tags: mysql, jsp, struts2, tiles

I am using strust2 and tiles for my project. Here is the code (*jsp*) for entering an ID.

```
<s:textfield    name="uniqueID"    label="Enter Unique ID"    required="required"/>
```

Here is the action file.

```
public String execute() throws Exception{
    SearchDao.search(selectedID,uniqueID);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The *dao* will retrieve image.

```
try{
    .
    .
    .
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next()){          
        InputStream originalImageStream = rs.getBinaryStream(1);

        File file = new File("Retina"+".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        while ((length = originalImageStream.read()) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(length);                 
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return "found";
```

Once the image is found this will return *found* and so action file will return *success*. Code in *struts.xml* is

```
<action name="search"       class="com.ActionClasses.SearchAction">
    <result name="success"  type="tiles">   found       </result>
    <result name="input"    type="tiles">   search      </result>
    <result name="error"    type="tiles">   notFound    </result>
</action>
```

here is the *tiles.xml* file.

```
<definition name="found" extends="home">
    <put-attribute name="myTitle"   value="searchSuccess"/>
    <put-attribute name="myBody"    value="/found.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

Now how can I display the retrieved image in *found.jsp*. I found some solutions in Internet but only for projects that uses struts2 or struts2 along with hibernate. I didn't find any solution for projects that use both strus2 and tiles. Can anyone help me. Thank you.

Comment: My question is How can I save the image in _bean_ and display it in _jsp_?

Comment: Use one of the solution you've found. Tiles is irrelevant in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out ... I have implemented the similar scenario in one of my projects but in spring, I guess it should work for you with little changes

This is what I had implemented. I created a controller (aka action in struts) like below

> 

```
@RequestMapping(value = "view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getImage(@RequestParam(value = "location") String location, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(location);
        response.setContentType("image/"+ext);
        try {
            File file = new File(location);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
            OutputStream baos = response.getOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, ext, baos);
            baos.flush();
            baos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("File Not Found: " + location, e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Can't read the File: " + location, e);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can't read input file: " + location, e);
        }

        return;
    }
```

**And then in the controller/action that server the actual view I did something like this**

```
    final String IMAGE_RESOLVER = "../../image/view?location=";
    Game game = gameService.populateGame(gameId);
    if(game.getThumbnailPath() != null) {
        game.setThumbnailPath(IMAGE_RESOLVER.concat(game.getThumbnailPath()));
    }
    mv.addObject("game", game); // set object to return to view
```

**When the DOM object with name "thumbnail" receives this string it calls the action mentioned above which returns it an image**

**Hope this works for you**